# External php file working in Magento1.9 but not in magento1.7

Tags: magento-1.7

I have prepared a code which check product with no images and than add an image to it form a folder with same name as that of product. In Magento 1.9 it is working perfectly. But when i try it on magento1.7 it throughs fatal error.
Here is my code

```
 <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
$mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('memory_limit', '600M');
ini_set('max_execution_time', 1800);
umask(0);
Mage::app('admin'); 
$products_model =  Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                ->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array("eq" => 1))
                ->load();  
$backendModel = $products_model->getResource()->getAttribute('media_gallery')->getBackend();

foreach ($products_model as $pid){
    $img = pathinfo($pid->getImageUrl())['basename'];
     echo 'Name  =  '.$pid->getName().'<br>';
    echo 'Image  =  '.$img.'<br>';
    if($img =='' || $img== 'image.jpg'){
        //live
        $ImagePath = "/var/www/vhosts/inriverimage/pics/".$pid->getName().".jpg"; // path of the image

        //local
        //$ImagePath = dirname(__FILE__)."/media/import/".$pid->getName().".jpg"; // path of the image
        
        if(file_exists($ImagePath)){
            echo 'Image  Found<br>';
            $products_model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($pid->getId()); 
            $products_model->addImageToMediaGallery($ImagePath, array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'), false);
            $products_model->save();
        }
        else{
            echo 'Image  Not found<br>';
        }
    }
   
}
?>
```

This code is working in Magento 1.9. But If i try run it in magento1.7
using following URL http://localhost/magento1.7/addimage.php it through following error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Strict Notice: Declaration of Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http::getBaseUrl() should be compatible with Zend_Controller_Request_Http::getBaseUrl($raw = false) in /var/www/vhosts/loruslive/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php on line 36' in /var/www/vhosts/loruslive/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php:245 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/vhosts/loruslive/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php(36): mageCoreErrorHandler(2048, 'Declaration of ...', '/var/www/vhosts...', 36, Array) #1 /var/www/vhosts/loruslive/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Autoload.php(93): include('/var/www/vhosts...') #2 [internal function]: Varien_Autoload->autoload('Mage_Core_Contr...') #3 /var/www/vhosts/loruslive/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1219): spl_autoload_call('Mage_Core_Contr...') #4 /var/www/vhosts/loruslive/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cookie.php(83): Mage_Core_Model_App->getRequest() #5 /var/www/vhosts/loruslive/httpdocs in /var/www/vhosts/loruslive/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php on line 245
```

Comment: remove E_Strict from your error reporting : E_ALL & ~E_STRICT

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed the problem by editing the file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php and changing the function getBaseUrl() as follows:

```
public function getBaseUrl($raw = false)
{
    $url = parent::getBaseUrl($raw);
    $url = str_replace('\\', '/', $url);
    return $url;
}
```